# Tree graph formatting in igraph R

Tags: r, tree, igraph

I have data of network data as follows:

```
library(igraph)

dnode<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")

dedge<-data.frame("From"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","f","f","f","f"), "To"=c("f","f","f","f","f","g","h","i","j","k"))
```

When I plot it in R I write code as follows:

```
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=dedge, vertices=dnode, directed=T)

l<- layout_as_tree

plot(net, vertex.shape="square", layout=l, edge.arrow.mode=2, edge.arrow.width=2, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
```

I get the output like this:

[image]

I want output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Sugiyama layout. The syntax is a bit different from other layouts. Rather than passing a network to `plot`, and layout to the `layout` argument, you pass `layout$extd_graph` and no layout argument. I find the Sugiyama layout much more flexible to use with layered layouts.

```
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(net)
plot(l$extd_graph, 
     vertex.shape="square", 
     vertex.label=as_ids(V(net)),
     edge.arrow.mode=2, 
     edge.arrow.width=2, 
     edge.arrow.size=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped a lot.

Comment: how to increase space between two vertexes. In above case, we have 5 up and 5 down vertexes. When I try to plot 25-30 vertices then they overlap each other and are not visible. if I use "hgap" it only accepts two values 0 or 1.